# Calling a Global String from another File in Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, variables, reactjs, global

I have a global variable that fetches an API URL and I want to add it to my action.js file.

mainUrl.js

```
const MAIN_URL="www.testexamplebeta.com"
```

action.js

```
import {MAIN_URL} from '../mainUrl'

export function fetchPets() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        console.log("THE URL IS", MAIN_URL)
        axios.get(`${MAIN_URL}/tests`)
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_TESTS,
                    payload: response
                });
            })
            .catch(() => {
                console.log("Can't fetch the test examples");
            });
    }
}
```

When I console.log the MAIN_URL I get undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should export your "global" variable like this:

```
export const MAIN_URL="www.testexamplebeta.com"
```